# How to time a MongoQuery from C#

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I try to timed a Mongo query in C# on a column with an index:

```
DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;
MongoCollection<BsonDocument> voteCol = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("XXX");
var query = new QueryDocument("YYY", "23915");
MongoCursor<BsonDocument> cursor = voteCol.Find(query).SetSortOrder(SortBy.Descending("ZZZ")).SetLimit(10).SetSkip(20);
TimeSpan elapsedTime = DateTime.Now - startTime;
Console.WriteLine("Elapsed: {0}, in seconds: {1}, in milliseconds: {2} ", 
elapsedTime, elapsedTime.TotalSeconds, elapsedTime.TotalMilliseconds, cursor.Count());
```

Everytime it is equal to 0 and I get the results.
Does it mean that it is too fast or did I missed something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you actually not loading data from mongodb. Data will be loaded when you start iterate through `MongoCursor`. You can easy use `ToList` method to load data from the database:

```
var data = voteCol.Find(query)
    .SetSortOrder(SortBy.Descending("ZZZ"))
    .SetLimit(10)
    .SetSkip(20)
    .ToList();
```

Also i suggest to use [Stopwatch](http://www.dotnetperls.com/stopwatch) to evaluate elapsed time.

Answer (score 0):

try [Stopwatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Like Andrew says, Mongo don't actually execute the query until you start iterating over the cursor, so your query isn't being executed.

The `Stopwatch` class is probably the best way to time the query from your application, but you can also benchmark your queries at the database using the MongoDB [Database Profiler](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Database+Profiler).